# Is there a gadget that reduces generalized geography to undirected graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, pspace, combinatorial-game-theory, two-player-games

The directed [Generalized Geography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_geography) game is well-known to be PSPACE-complete, however, I could not find anything for the undirected version. I saw that in [Hans L. Bodlaender, Complexity of path-forming games, Theoretical Computer Science, Volume 110, Issue 1, 15 March 1993, Pages 215-245](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759390357Y/pdf?md5=f2e5b46744aa1e817cd19dc930b21c6e&pid=1-s2.0-030439759390357Y-main.pdf) (thx to Marzio De Biasi for the link) it is posed as an open problem. Is it still open?

In fact, I wonder if there is a simple gadget that we can put in the place of every directed edge to make a straight-forward reduction from the directed version. Is it known that no such gadget can exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Undirected (Vertex) Geography is in P. In particular, the game on graph $G$ with starting vertex $v$ is a win for player 1 if and only if every maximum matching of $G$ uses the vertex $v$. This can be checked in polynomial time.

The above is Theorem 1.1 from the paper "Undirected Edge Geography", by Fraenkel, Scheinerman and Ullman, Theoretical Computer Science 1993.